# Cannot save changed profile in Netbeans

Tags: linux-mint, kde, netbeans

I am tring to chang fonts and colors in Netbeans by  tools > options > fonts & colors
When I close netbeans, all changed fonts and colors would be deleted and restarting netbeans will be same as first profile.